# Visual Studio only uses 2 spaces as indentation for XAML, despite being set to 4

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

In Visual Studio 22 17.6.5 I clicked on
**Tools** -> **Options** -> **TextEditor** -> **XAML** -> **Tabs**

and set the following options:
**Indenting** *smart*
**Tab size** 4
**Indent size** 4
[o] *Insert spaces*
[ ] *Keep tabs*

Still, when I press <kbd>tab</kbd> or when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to trigger the auto formatter, the indentation level is 2 spaces.

**How can I fix this?**